# How to change tags using xml::Twig?

Tags: xml, xml-twig

I am new to xml::Twig, I need change one to one linking tag in my xml, I have no concept that one,.. I face lot issue...

My Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<p><a href="#fn001" id="fn_001">1</a> this a footnote reference</p>
<p>This a simple text</p>
<p>This a simple text</p>
<p>This a simple text</p>
<p><a href="#fn_001" id="fn001">1</a> this a footnote reference</p>
</root>
```

need as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<p><a href="#fn001" id="fn_001">1</a> this a footnote reference</p>
<p>This a simple text</p>
<p>This a simple text</p>
<p>This a simple text</p>
<p><anchor href="#fn_001" id="fn001">1</anchor> this a footnote reference</p>
</root>
```

i need to take first `<a>` tag href link, and i need search where it call, that tag only change as anchor with in document. And When i reached sec one no need find that because it will change as anchor right...., This concept using many one to one `<a>` tag, first one only no need change ..... thanks

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $xml = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {
},
pretty_print => 'indented',
keep_encoding => 1,
);
$xml->parsefile("sample.xml");
```

I using this code, but i did't do anything in this code... because i haven't solution... is it possible ....?